# Этапы работы компилятора MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, компилятор

Уважаемые Гуру, подскажите, где можно найти информацию по этапам работы MSVC?
Насколько я понимаю они отличаются от классической схемы GCC Препрцессор-Транслятор-Ассемблер-Компоновщик.
Поверхностное гугление не принесло результатов. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: gcc уже давно отошел от такой схемы.

Comment: [C/C++ projects and build systems in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/projects-and-build-systems-cpp?view=msvc-160#c-compilation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом выводе системы сборки. После сборки проекта в окне вывода Visual Studio выбираем "Показать выходные данные из:" - "Сборка". Результат выглядит так:

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: CppConsole, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Сборка начата 19.10.2021 9:08:23.
1>Целевой объект InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Создание "Debug\CppConsole.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild", так как было задано "AlwaysCreate".
1>Целевой объект ClCompile:
1>  CppConsole.cpp
1>Целевой объект Link:
1>  CppConsole.vcxproj -> C:\PROJECTS_2017\CppConsole\Debug\CppConsole.exe
1>Целевой объект FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Файл "Debug\CppConsole.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" удаляется.
1>  Обращение к "Debug\CppConsole.tlog\CppConsole.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Сборка успешно завершена.
1>    Предупреждений: 0
1>    Ошибок: 0
1>
1>Прошло времени 00:00:01.04
========== Сборка: успешно: 1, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Видно, что в сборке есть несколько этапов, которые представлены "Целевыми объектами" (Target) MSBuild. Эти целевые объекты для С++ документированы здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/msbuild-visual-cpp-overview?view=msvc-160#targets. В нашем случае были такие этапы:

- **InitializeBuildStatus**. Считывает результаты последней сборки, что позволяет выполнять сборку только тех входных файлов, которые изменились.
- **ClCompile**. Вызывает компилятор, cl.exe, для каждого входного файла .cpp, получая на выходе объектный файл. Препроцессор включен в этот этап.
- **Link**. Вызывает компоновщик, link.exe, подавая на вход объектные файлы и необходимые зависимости.
- **FinalizeBuildStatus**. Соответственно, сохраняет результаты этой сборки в файл lastbuildstate, чтобы их можно было прочитать при последующих сборках.

Можно узнать больше о содержании этих этапов, включив более подробный вывод MSBuild (Параметры - Проекты и решения - Сборка и запуск - Уровень детализации выходных данных сборки проекта MSBuild - выбрать "Подробные").

Компоновка в проекте Visual Studio является отдельным этапом, но cl.exe может и автоматически вызывать компоновщик. Система проектов передает компилятору параметр [/c](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-compile-without-linking?view=msvc-160), который отключает автоматическую компоновку, вероятно, потому что большинство реальных проектов имеют дополнительные этапы сборки, вроде компиляции ресурсов, которые должны идти до компоновки.

Answer (score 2):

MSVC предоставляет инструменты [Build Insights](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-c-build-insights/) которые отображают и позволяют профилировать все стадии сборки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понять бы еще, как этим профилировщиком пользоваться. Гайд явно устарел - копировать dll-ки и править файлы настроек руками уже не надо. Но когда я последний раз это пробовал, не понял куда смотреть в WPA...

Comment: А в виде статьи, или гайда есть информация по топику? Смотрю, в MSVC все туго с этим делом.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я в итоге не осилил, но кой какую информацию удалось собрать через `/d2cgsummary` и `/d1reportTime`